# How to make Antlr4 stop parsing when a rule is completed

Tags: antlr4

I have to parse parts of a file where I have expressions like :

```
garbage garbage garbage
BEGIN <something> END
garbage garbage...
```

Here, I want to parse everything between BEGIN and END, keeping the garbage aside.

I tried to write a parser which has rules like :

```
rule : BEGIN expr END;
expr : ... ;
```

which correctly parses my expression, if it's the only thing I have in my file. Sadly, when I try to kick the parser when I meet a "BEGIN" in my file, the parser will correctly parse the expression, but will then try to fetch some other token after the "END".

I have read the part abiut fyzzy grammar in ANTLR4 book, but this is not what I want, because the result of the parsing will impact the remaining of the file (basically, the result of the parsing will produce a set of substitutions to apply in the following text).

What I'm looking for is a way to tell the parser to stop after the "END" keyword. I have tried to override the TokenStream to produce a Token.EOF when END is met, with this modified rule set :

```
rule : BEGIN expr EOF;
expr : ... ;
```

with code like :

```
public Token LT(int k) 
{
    Token token = super.LT( k );

    if ( token.getType() == MyParser.END )
    {
        token = new CommonToken(Token.EOF,"");
    }

    return token;
}
```

but in this case, the stream is closed, and I can't anymore use it for the remaining file...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a special mode in your lexer to consume the garbage as a single `GARBAGE` token. In the following example code, I have `GarbageMode` as the separate mode, which requires you to explicitly call `lexer.setMode(GarbageMode)` after creating a new instance of the lexer. The alternative is placing the `Garbage` and `GarbageMode_BEGIN` rules in the default mode and moving the remaining rules from the default mode into a new mode, e.g. `MainMode`.

```
BEGIN
  : 'BEGIN'
  ;

END
  : 'END' -> mode(GarbageMode)
  ;

mode GarbageMode;

  GARBAGE
    : .+? (BEGIN | EOF) -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

  GarbageMode_BEGIN
    : BEGIN -> type(BEGIN), mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;
```

The key to making the above lexer work is overriding the `Lexer.emit` method to reset the input stream position prior to creating a `GARBAGE` token. An example of this is available in [PositionAdjustingLexer.g4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/PositionAdjustingLexer.g4), with the corresponding unit test [`testPositionAdjustingLexer()`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/d94ce39d09058781c49e60bbda28b52a9754fb1c/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/TestLexerExec.java#L609-L637). In your case, you'll simply remove the last 5 characters from the `GARBAGE` token if the text of the token ends with `BEGIN`.

Comment: It should work, thanks for the trick (assuming I can mark the inputStream, but here, I have to do my homeworks). FYI, I have used a 'fuzzy parser' which swallows everything that is not in my grammar, but it means I have to read the file twice. What you propose will save me one phase.

That would be great to have a feature that stop fetching tokens when the entry rule has been completed. Something like a pseudo token EOP (End Of Parsing) could help. wdyt ?

Comment: @EmmanuelLécharny You would eventually run into [issue #118](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/118) if you try that.

Comment: Actually, I ran into #118 :-) I was expected to get an exception, but instead, the lexer just read everything up to the end of the file... That's why I posted the question.